# Ultra basic join I seem to be doing wrong. Left join by hours using AS and after Group by?

Tags: mysql, join

Just spent what must of been a good 4 hours browsing stackoverflow and god knows what what else and I just cant figure this out.

I have a query that gets me the (counted) number of something and grouped by the hour of the day.

I have a table with hours in it.. hours.hour contains 24 rows from 0,1,2,3,4 for each hour.

Anyway, I just cant see how to get these two to join.

Initial query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as number
     ,  HOUR(timestarted) as hournum 
  FROM logs  
 WHERE `timestarted` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 365 DAY) 
   AND acuit = '1234567890'  
 GROUP 
    BY HOUR(`timestarted`);

+--------+---------+
| number | hournum |
+--------+---------+
|      4 |      10 |
|      6 |      11 |
|      5 |      12 |
|     10 |      13 |
|      2 |      14 |
|      3 |      15 |
|     18 |      17 |
|     29 |      18 |
|     11 |      19 |
|     12 |      20 |
|      9 |      21 |
|      2 |      22 |
+--------+---------+
```

How I have the following table:

```
 select * from hours;

+------+
| hour |
+------+
|    0 |
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
|    5 |
|    6 |
|    7 |
|    8 |
|    9 |
|   10 |
|   11 |
|   12 |
|   13 |
|   14 |
|   15 |
|   16 |
|   17 |
|   18 |
|   19 |
|   20 |
|   21 |
|   22 |
|   23 |
+------+
```

Id like to be able to get the outputs merged by hour. So essentially hours that dont have a "number" as just shown as zero rather than the inital output that didnt contain null hours.

Any ideas?

Ive tried doing a LEFT JOIN ON hours.hour=hournum but failed and my joining sucks.

Every link on google is now purple and im outta ideas.

Any thoughts on this would be wonderful.

Cheers
G

Comment: Change WHERE to AND

Comment: Hmm, that just errors..

SELECT COUNT(*) as number
     ,  HOUR(timestarted) as hournum 
  FROM logs  
 AND `timestarted` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 365 DAY) 
   AND acuit = '1234567890'  
 GROUP 
    BY HOUR(`timestarted`);

Comment: That doesn' t make sense. Change that back please. Could you add the relevant part of your logs table? Maybe the sql for it. That will be easier to test it for us.

Comment: I don't think you need a join, since hournum is an hour right? So what do you need the join for?

Comment: Also, can you clarify the "hours that dont have a number" part? I don't get that line. Maybe by an example?

Comment: I'm talking about the query we can't see.

Comment: You have the querys. This is it..

By hours that dont have a number, i mean hours that dont have rows. Hence the need to join a table that has "all hours of the day" otherwise ijust get results like the top one.

Comment: There's a query with a left join in it

Comment: Thats what I am trying to do and need help with? I essentially have the two result sets above and need to merge them. (Where hour and hournum match eachother)

Comment: I guess to make it clearer, I am trying to draw a line chart showing the "number" by hour. As the first result only gives results for some hours (as some hours dont have numbers) i need to fill them in for all hours that have zero. So i have a "number" for all 24 hours of the day (albeit some will be zero)

Comment: Tried something like this at the end: 
 LEFT JOIN ON hours.hour = hournum; but i dont really get it.

Comment: It's alright; we get what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following. In what follows `ints' is simply a table of integers (0-9) - but it's really no different from using your hour table. Note that this result is for a single day. Multiple dates is more complicated, but really issues of data display like this (like what to do with missing rows) are best to left application code.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,time_started DATETIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (time_started) VALUES
('2017-01-01 10:00:00'),
('2017-01-01 10:23:00'),
('2017-01-01 10:27:00'),
('2017-01-01 10:30:00'),
('2017-01-01 10:35:00'),

('2017-01-01 11:00:00'),
('2017-01-01 11:23:00'),
('2017-01-01 11:27:00'),

('2017-01-01 12:00:00'),
('2017-01-01 12:23:00'),
('2017-01-01 12:27:00'),

('2017-01-01 13:00:00'),
('2017-01-01 13:23:00'),
('2017-01-01 13:27:00'),

('2017-01-01 14:00:00'),
('2017-01-01 14:23:00'),
('2017-01-01 14:27:00'),

('2017-01-01 15:00:00'),
('2017-01-01 15:23:00'),
('2017-01-01 15:27:00'),

('2017-01-02 10:00:00'),
('2017-01-02 11:23:00'),
('2017-01-02 13:27:00');


SELECT i2.i*10+i1.i n
     , COUNT(x.id) total 
  FROM ints i1 
  JOIN ints i2 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table x 
    ON HOUR(time_started) = i2.i*10+i1.i 
   AND time_started BETWEEN '2017-01-01 00:00;00' AND '2017-01-02:00:00:00'
 WHERE i2.i*10+i1.i <=23 
 GROUP  
    BY n;

+----+-------+
| n  | total |
+----+-------+
|  0 |     0 |
|  1 |     0 |
|  2 |     0 |
|  3 |     0 |
|  4 |     0 |
|  5 |     0 |
|  6 |     0 |
|  7 |     0 |
|  8 |     0 |
|  9 |     0 |
| 10 |     5 |
| 11 |     3 |
| 12 |     3 |
| 13 |     3 |
| 14 |     3 |
| 15 |     3 |
| 16 |     0 |
| 17 |     0 |
| 18 |     0 |
| 19 |     0 |
| 20 |     0 |
| 21 |     0 |
| 22 |     0 |
| 23 |     0 |
+----+-------+
```